# How to use interpolation to calculate a force based on angle

Tags: python, interpolation, angle, curve

I am trying to make a python script that will output a force based on a measured angle. The inputs are time, the curve and the angle, but I am having trouble using interpolation to fit the force to the curve. I looked at scipy.interpolate, but I'm not sure it will help me because the points aren't evenly spaced.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

`numpy.interp` does not require your points to be evenly distributed. I'm not certain if you mean by "The inputs are time, the curve and the angle" that you have three independent variables, if so you will have to adapt it quite a bit... But for one-variable problems, `interp` is the way to go.